# NotifyIcon se vuelve loco. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Comento mi aplicación rápidamente y después el problema:

Tengo dos Forms, cada uno de ellos tiene un botón que abre el otro y cierra ese mismo (cambia de Form, vaya). El `Form1` tiene un `NotifyIcon` para, en caso de cerrar ambas ventanas, poder volver a abrirlo. Todo esto funciona bien. El problema viene cuando vuelvo de `Form2` al `Form1`, que me crea otro icono igual en la barra de notificaciones, habiendo dos. Si vuelvo al `Form2` desde el `Form1` no pasa nada, pero al volver al `Form1` me crea otro icono y así infinitamente, solo al ir del `Form2` al `Form1`.

Os dejo el código que creo que afecta a esto a ver si me podéis echar una mano porque no soy capaz de ver el problema.

Boton del `Form2` que vuelve al `Form1`:

```
Private Sub FTTA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FTTA.Click

    Dim goAlmacen As New FormAlmacen
    goAlmacen.Show()

    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

El `Load` y el `Notify` del `Form1`

```
Private Sub FormAlmacen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    vIn.Select()

    Dim r As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea
    Location = New Point(r.Width - Width, r.Height - Height)

    vIn.Text = String.Empty
    vOUT.Text = String.Empty
    txt1.Text = String.Empty
    txt2.Text = String.Empty
    vNombre.Text = String.Empty

End Sub


Private Sub Vnotificación_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Vnotificación.MouseClick
    vIn.Select()
    Me.Show()
    vIn.Text = String.Empty
    vOUT.Text = String.Empty
    txt1.Text = String.Empty
    txt2.Text = String.Empty
    vNombre.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

Por último en el diseño está puesto de la siguiente forma, no se si tendrá que ver pero por si acaso (elimino las partes de código que no interesan.)

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.Vnotificación = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(Me.components)
    resources.ApplyResources(Me.Vnotificación, "Vnotificación")
End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Vnotificación As NotifyIcon
```

quiza hay alguna forma de "matar" un icono y sustituirlo por otro si existe o algo por el estilo, pero no soy capaz de hacerlo. ¿Alguna idea?

Edito:

Código del botón que lleva del `Form1` al `Form2`:

```
  Private Sub ButtonVolver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FATT.Click

        Dim goTrabajos As New FormFases
        goTrabajos.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código del boton del Form1 que muestra el form2?

Comment: Ahí lo pongo, es igual que el del botón que lleva del form2 al form1

Comment: He añadido una respuesta, echale un vistazo a ver si lo entiendes.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema grave con tu código. Estás ocultando el formulario activo cuando pasas de uno a otro, y en ese momento creas una nueva instancia del formulario a mostrar. Haciéndolo así, el `NotifyIcon` es el menor de los problemas, ya que estas generando inútilmente formularios que van quedando ocultos y que puede llegar un momento en el que te quedes incluso sin memoria.

Ya que te interesa que el formulario "principal" esté ocultos para poder mostrarle a voluntad y que el `NotifyIcon` este siempre activo, lo que debes hacer es añadir un constructor al segundo formulario que reciba la instancia del formulario "principal" que lo está llamando. De esa manera, teniendo esa instancia disponible puedes llamar a su método `Show` en lugar de tener que crear uno nuevo.

Resumiendo. Básicamente,en el formulario `FormFases` creas una variable de tipo `FormAlmacen` y un nuevo constructor que reciba la instancia del formulario principal:

```
Dim formPrincipal As FormAlmacen

Public Sub New(Byval formp As FormAlmacen)
    formPrincipal = formp
End Sub
```

Ahora ya tenemos una referencia al formulario principal. De esa manera, cuando queramos mostrarla hacemos lo siguiente:

```
Private Sub FTTA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FTTA.Click
    formPrincipal.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Lo único que nos falta ocultar el `FormAlmacen` cuando llamemos al `FormFases`,como ya lo tenías, y mandar la instancia del `FormAlmacen` al crear el `FormFases`, enviando al constructor `Me` como parámetro:

```
Private Sub ButtonVolver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FATT.Click
    Dim goTrabajos As New FormFases(Me)
    goTrabajos.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Probablemente haya otras maneras mejores de gestionarlo, pero esta es una solución sencilla.

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo lo que estaba haciendo mal... muy cafre por mi parte. Lo unico la primera parte de código me salta un error tal que `la clave 'overloads' se usa para sobrecargar los miembros heredados; no use la palabra clave 'overloads' cuando sobrecargue un procedimiento 'sub new'` que quizá soy yo que lo estoy poniendo donde no es jeje

Comment: @CharlieMR No,es más probable que sea fallo mio ya que nunca programo en vb.net sino en C#. Quita el "overloads" que parece no es necesario para el constructor... He editado la respuesta

Comment: Ahora me salta error en el último fragmento, en la declaración de `goTrabajos` y pone _No se especificó un argumento para el parámetro 'formp' de 'Public Sub New(formp As FormAlmacen)'_... Perdón por marearte tanto @Pikoh .

Comment: No te preocupes, el problema es que al hacer el código de cabeza y no probarlo pasan esas cosas. El error es porque tienes un constructor que espera la instancia del formulario principal, asi que en la creación hay que añadirlo (`Dim goTrabajos As New FormFases(Me)`). He editado la respuesta

Comment: Eso lo probé antes de escribir el anterior comentario y me lleva a un formulario vacío por completo al darle al botón hmhm

Answer (score 1):

Si tu aplicación va a usar mas de un formulario y quieres manejar notifyicon, lo ideal es que bases tu aplicación en un ApplicationContext y no usesun formulario como aplicación.

Creas una clase que herede de ApplicationContext:

```
Public Class AppContext
     Inherits ApplicationContext

     private withevents TrayIcon as NotifyIcon
     private withevents TrayIconContextMenu  as ContextMenuStrip
     private withevents CloseMenuItem as ToolStripMenuItem

     public Sub New()
          InitializeComponent()
          ' cualquier otra cosa que quieras inicializar
     End

     private Sub InitializeComponent()
          TrayIcon = new NotifyIcon()
          CloseMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem()
          TrayIconContextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip()

          ' aqui inicializas los tres componentes 

         TrayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = TrayIconContextMenu
     End

    private sub TrayIcon_DoubleClick(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles TrayIcon.DoubleClick
         ' aqui puedes crear los forms y mostrarlos
    End sub

     private sub CloseMenuItem_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles CloseMenuItem.Click
          Application.Exit()
     End sub
End
```

Y cambias

```
Application.Run(new Formulario())
```

Por

```
 Application.Run(new AppContext())
```